# TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'push' of undefined in two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, here, I am trying to create a two dimensional array; an array of arrays. However, whenever I try to push a value to the nested array, I receive the error seen in the title. In these for loops, the 'b' array is full of a list of strings, which are all received in a certain format, and the code then breaks it up and pushes it to the values in the 2-D array for further working.

```
var c = []

for(var u = 0; u < b.length; u++){
  c[u] = new Array(0);
  for(var y = 0; y < b[u].length; y++){
    c[u][y].push(b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf('\"'), b[u].indexOf(",")));
    b[u] = b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf(',') + 1);
  }
}
```

I've looked on the other solutions here on stackoverflow; Either I can't wrap my head around them, or they're not applicable here. I can't tell what's wrong here. Help, please.

Comment: Well for one thing, when the process starts, `b.length` is zero; at the start there's nothing in the arrays yet, so the outer loop will perform no iterations.

Comment: b already contains strings, filled by another loop. I'll clarify, sorry.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm almost sure there's a better way than a nested for loop and stateful calls to `.push()`.

Comment: It's hard to tell what sort of results you want, but it probably should just be `c[u].push(...)` instead of `c[u][y].push(...)`.

Comment: It's interpreting an input in a list format, separated by commas. For some reason, where I'm getting it from insists on using a '"' around each element in the list. I'm going to be doing other things to these strings afterwards, though, I'm just trying to mince it into chunks.

Comment: @Pointy Oh, right. I completely missed that. Sorry 'bout that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var c = []

for(var u = 0; u < b.length; u++){
  c[u] = new Array(0);
  for(var y = 0; y < b[u].length; y++){
    // NOT WORKING
    // c[u][y].push(b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf('\"'), b[u].indexOf(",")));

    // WORKING
    c[u].push(b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf('\"'), b[u].indexOf(",")));

    // WORKING
    c[u][y] = b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf('\"'), b[u].indexOf(","));

    b[u] = b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf(',') + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: glad to know it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you already declare an array `b` as `blank` without any value `var b = []`.

So, `b.length` will be `0`.

Then this condition `for(var u = 0; u < b.length; u++)` will not execute and code will not work.

**Update :**

So, you can directly use :

```
c[u].push(b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf('\"'), b[u].indexOf(",")));
```

Comment: b contains strings. Earlier, var b = [] was used as a placeholder for this question only. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to use `.push` on something that is already a value:

```js
/**
 * c is an array: []
 */
var c = []

for (var u = 0; u < b.length; u++) {
  /**
   * c[u] is a subarray: [u: []]
   */
  c[u] = new Array(0);
  for (var y = 0; y < b[u].length; y++) {
    /**
     * c[u][y] is a value, currently undefined: [u: [y: ??]]
     */
    c[u][y].push(b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf('\"'), b[u].indexOf(",")));
    b[u] = b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf(',') + 1);
  }
}
```

For what you want, you use either of the following:

```js
// Value (replace as needed)
var value = b[u].substring(b[u].indexOf('\"'), b[u].indexOf(","));

// Option 1
c[u][y] = value;

// Option 2
c[u].push(value);
```